# Converting quick release to solid axle

Tags: axle, conversion, quick-release

I want to swap out my front wheel (solid axle) with another wheel (quick release axle). Issue is, I DO NOT want to use quick release for various reasons.

I have tried janking out the quick release axle without luck (having seen a few tutorials online). Being a fool, I've scratched/damaged the hub/axle quite a bit. Using my common sense, I figured that there is a little ring on both sides that is stopping the axle from sliding out (see picture underneath):

[image: Picture of quick release axle]

You can't really see the damage in the picture above but I've quite messed up the metal/paint on the hub/axle on the other side.

1. How do I get this thing out if possible? (by removing the little ring perhaps? I tried but can't really get the ring out, it's on there tight with little room to work with)
2. Can I even put in a solid axle in this wheel/hub?

Crucial information:

- Current front wheel is a Miche Pistard WR
- 'new' front wheel is a Campagnolo Khamsin G3. Even though I've almost obliberated the hub/axle, wheel seems to be spinning fine and true still.
- I am a mere novice with no bicycle skills whatsoever but I am trying to learn.

Comment: Im curious, why will you replace the Miche wheel on your track bike with a road wheel?

Comment: I am planning on adding a front-brake since I will be riding it in a suburban area, so I need a wheel with a brake surface. I have emailed Miche and asked if I can just run brakes on their Pistard WR wheels even though they are NMSW (non machined side walls). They heavily recommended against me doing so, since the walls are too thin and slope downward, which would make for an awkward angle for the brakepads to push on.

Comment: Indeed, these wheels are for track use and for track use only. When you take your bike out of your velodrome you will need brakes.
As far as I know, 9mm bolts go into the same drop outs  as quick release skewers. When you look at your hub you see some stubs of 9 mm bolts with a hole. These go into your fork. The QR itself is much narrower than the slots in the fork as it only clamps it all together. It doesn't take side-ways forces. That is, you _might not have to replace anything on your front hub_. It should fit as it is.

Comment: Seems to be some confusion here between Solid Axle and Through Axle.    Your photo looks like a Through Axle, and you want to swap to an unpictured wheel with a Quick Release but change that wheel's axle to a solid (nutted) axle ?  Please confirm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I even put in a solid axle in this wheel/hub?

Probably not. The axles of QR hubs are generally not designed to be removed and replaced with a through-axle. Some hubs are designed for both retention systems and can be converted. This does not look like one of them. I've never seen a rim brake hub with a through axle.

Comment: The Miche wheel is for track racing. Solid axle here really means solid axle (as in nut and bolts) and not through axle (as in the new hub standard). (As an aside, the bike may not have brakes at all. It seems the Miche wheels rims have no brake track.)

Comment: Yes, I ment nutted/solid axle. Also, the bike has indeed no brakes, but I am planning on installing a front-brake, which is the reason why I'm switching wheels. You're nevertheless right, I've learned that hub's and manufacturers all have their own specifications, measurements, and most of them aren't ment to be just taken apart like that. Wasted a few bucks today, but learnt a lot. Thank you!

Comment: QR and solid axles are captured inside the hub, Some contact ball bearings directly, some run in replaceable cartridge bearings. You might be able to replace with a solid threaded axle but it will involve taking the hub apart.